# Best way to implement thread safe Point3DCollection in C#

Tags: c#, thread-safety, coordinates

What is the best way to make a **Point3DCollection** (and a Vector3DCollection) **thread safe**?

I have to create those collections in a main class that call a method from another class, in which I create each collection for each frame. The collections from the main class are there to store the collections from the previous frame so I can compare them to the new ones in the called method. I'm new to programming so this way of doing it might not be the best one, feel free to advise me if needed. I found the **ConcurrentDictionary** thread-safe collection but then I **lose** the very useful **Point3DCollection[Point3D].X property** (as well as the .Y and .Z ones) (or I didn't find a way to make it work, that's a possibility). 
Also, at the end of the called method, I update the collections from the calling class so I **can't use** **Freeze** or **Lock** (or at least that's what I understood, might be wrong too).

The error I get, when a if statement checks the count of a collection from the main class, is "The calling thread cannot access this object because another thread is proprietary". I understand the error but can't find a way to fix it.

Can someone help me please? Thanks!

**EDIT**: the error is triggered when I try to access an element by index (collection1 = collection in the called method works but collection1.Add(collection[0]) doesn't for example)

Comment: You need to understand and/or decide what "thread safe" means. Thread safe collections almost always revolve around making the internal data structures thread safe, but they do not allow you to use them in multiple steps and guarantee consistency. Example. `var x = collection[0].X; var y = collection[0].Y; var z = collection[0].Z;`, **no** collection can guarantee that you're still talking about the same point in those 3 statements, unless you have an immutable collection. Instead, grab the entire point into a local variable, and then grab X, Y and Z from that point.

Comment: Might be the wrong word, I just though it was that, sorry! What other word would you use to describe this (so I can clarify the post)?

Comment: No, you probably mean thread safety, but you will not be able to use `collection[index].X` safely, no matter which collection you use, so you shouldn't. The exception message you've posted though makes little sense, what does it mean by "another thread is proprietary", did you copy this correctly?

Comment: That's what I do in the called method: for each point I need, I add the x, y, z coordinates to a Point3D Struct, then I add it to a Point3DCollection to get a skeleton. In the calling class, I declare another Point3DCollection to store the previous skeleton. Updating the previous skeleton with new one works fine, my problem is when I use the previous skeleton in an if statement. I hope this clarifies a little bit what I'm trying to ask.
(This is the second part of my answer to the first comment, took too long to edit, my bad)

Comment: I translated it from French but I'm sure of the translation. I though I knew what it means but apparently not. I thought it meant I couldn't use the collection in another class

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I checked and you're right, the problem happens when I try to access an element by index. What would you advise me to do?